# Как расположить background?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как расположить  фон  таким вот образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что сейчас у меня выходит:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/9hyZwct/bg.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/9hyZwct/bg.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```